# Neo4j 3.2.0 and Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

Neo4j 3.2.0 was announced yesterday.

When will it be possible to use Spring Data Neo4j with Neo4j 3.2.0 ? What version of SDN should be used with Neo4j 3.2.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 minor issues with cypher in Neo4j 3.2.0 that cause ogm not to work properly. Both can be solved by providing default cypher version as a workaround:

```
cypher.default_language_version=3.1
```

in `conf/neo4j.conf` file.

Otherwise it is should be just a matter of pointing to 3.2.0 database or  changing dependencies in case of embedded.

Comment: Thanks. What version of OGM/SDN should be used with Neo4j 3.2.0 ?

Comment: Latest stable - 2.1.2 and 4.2.3 should be fine.